# How to capture response time of each request in JMeter?

Tags: javascript, java, https, jmeter, preprocessor

Need to capture response time in each request going in JMeter. Do I need to add any Listener or any Preprocessor? Or is there any way to capture it in View Result Tree?

Tried on JavaScript code and few other Listeners. Please let me know if there is an easy way to capture this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are using the response time of your request for, there are two possibilities for *when* the value of the response time for your request is needed that will determine *how* to extract this information:

1. **Knowing the response time of a request after your test is completed:**

   This is probably the most common scenario, where you would like to analyze the response times for many requests after your test completes.  Response times are written to the [.JTL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) file that is compiled while your test is running and where most post-test data analysis comes from.  `JTL` files are comma-delimited flat data files.  Specifically, you can find this in the `elapsed` column within this file:

   [image]

   The most common use of this file is displaying your test results in the [JMeter Dashboard Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), which includes several response time analyses.
   (You can read more general information about interpreting the JMeter Dashboard Report [here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2022/05/use-cases-jmeter-dashboard/).)  Additionally, any spreadsheet application can open the `.JTL` file simply by changing the file extension to `.CSV`.
2. **Knowing the response time of a request while the test is running:**

   If you need to know the response time of a request while your test is running, you can accomplish this with a post-processor.  The following line of *JSR223* code will save the response time for the previous request to a JMeter variable:

   `vars.put("lastResponseTime", String.valueOf(prev.getTime()));`

   Using the `prev.getTime()` function obtains the response time in milliseconds for the previous request, and using `vars.put(...)` will allow you to later retrieve this value using `vars.get(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results in GUI mode - take a look at [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener:

[image]

If you're [running your JMeter test in non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) - the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) will contain the response time for each sampler by default:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should use Listeners like Summary Report/Aggregate Report/View Results in Table
to get the response times.